# How do I extract the IP Address from a successful ping command?

Tags: windows-10, ping, ip-address, remote-shutdown

With a lot of help from another user I was able cut characters out of a single output from CMD. I then added my next part of code from where he left me with variable `_3octet`. My code is scanning all the IP addresses associated with the gateway the computer is connected to and snags only the ones that have a reply. From there I get a list of IP's that have replied.

```
Reply from 192.168.1.67: bytes=32 time=288ms TTL=64

Reply from 192.168.1.72: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Reply from 192.168.1.73: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=64

Reply from 192.168.1.75: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Reply from 192.168.1.76: bytes=32 time=155ms TTL=64

Reply from 192.168.1.88: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=255
```

From there I want to grab only the IP addresses, so cutting away everything except for "192.168.1.#", to be used in a future part of the program. Similar to the begining part of the code with the `_3octet` variable.
Here is my code.

```
@echo off
setlocal
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem throw away everything except the IPv4 address line 
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`ipconfig ^| findstr /i "ipv4"`) do (
rem we have for example "IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.42.78"
rem split on : and get 2nd token
for /f delims^=^:^ tokens^=2 %%b in ('echo %%a') do (
    rem we have " 192.168.42.78"
    rem split on . and get 4 tokens (octets)
    for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%c in ("%%b") do (
        set _o1=%%c
        set _o2=%%d
        set _o3=%%e
        set _o4=%%f
        rem strip leading space from first octet
        set _3octet=!_o1:~1!.!_o2!.!_o3!.
        echo !_3octet!
        )
    )
)
cd C:\Windows
for /l %%i IN (1,1,254) do ping -n 1 !_3octet!%%i | for /f delims^=^:^ tokens^=1 %%g in (find /i "bytes=32") do (
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%j in ("%%g") do (
    set _o1=%%j
    set _o2=%%k
    set _o3=%%l
    set _o4=%%m
    set _4octet=!_o1:~11!.!_o2!.!_o3!.!_o4!
    echo !_4octet!
    )
)
endlocal
```

I'm getting `: was unexpected at this time.` as an output multiple times. Which tells me that it is trying to ping every address 1-254 and not the ones that come up as a reply. Needless to say my code isn't working as I hoped.

I was planning on using that final list of IP addresses in this code: `shutdown -r -m \\192.168.1.1 -t 10` in order to shut down the computers connected to the gateway.

If this is at all confusing let me know. Thank you.

Comment: `for /l %%i in (1,1,254) do ping -n 1 !_3octet!%%i do (
 for /f "delims=: tokens=1" %%g in (find /i "bytes=32")`

That comes up as "Bad parameter do."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I want to grab only the IP addresses from the successful pings

I'm not going to try and fix the 2nd part of your batch file, it is easier to write it from scratch.

Use the following batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem throw away everything except the IPv4 address line 
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`ipconfig ^| findstr /i "ipv4"`) do (
rem we have for example "IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.42.78"
rem split on : and get 2nd token
for /f delims^=^:^ tokens^=2 %%b in ('echo %%a') do (
    rem we have " 192.168.42.78"
    rem split on . and get 4 tokens (octets)
    for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%c in ("%%b") do (
        set _o1=%%c
        set _o2=%%d
        set _o3=%%e
        set _o4=%%f
        rem strip leading space from first octet
        set _3octet=!_o1:~1!.!_o2!.!_o3!.
        echo !_3octet!
        )
    )
)
for /l %%i in (1,1,254) do (
  rem do the ping and grab the 3rd token (ip address) if it succeeds (TTL= is found)
  for /f "usebackq tokens=3" %%j in (`ping -n 1 !_3octet!%%i ^| find "TTL="`) do (
      rem we have ip address with a trailing :
      rem split on . and get the 4th token (last octet)
      rem we don't need the first 3 as they are already in !_3octet!
      for /f "tokens=4 delims=." %%k in ("%%j") do (
        set _o4=%%k
        rem strip trailing : from last octet
        set _4octet=!_o4:~0,-1!
        echo !_4octet!
      )
    )
  )
endlocal
```

Notes:

- The value you want is saved in `!_3octet!!_4octet!` where

  - !_3octet! is the same as before
  - !_4octet! is the last octet (you don't need two extract the first 3 octets twice!)
- You don't need `cd C:\Windows`
- One of the IP addresses will be your gateway (router) address, you probably don't want to try and run `shutdown` on the gateway!

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [ipconfig](http://ss64.com/nt/ipconfig.html) - Configure IP (Internet Protocol configuration)
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.
- [setlocal](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) - Set options to control the visibility of environment variables in a batch file.
- [variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) - Extract part of a variable (substring).

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Thank you very much!

Comment: @SamuelPauk I'm off to sleep now (it's 1AM here). If it doesn't work as it is (quite possible as it is complex parsing and I don't have a network to test it on) please let me know and I will take a look at it tomorrow.